# Is there a symbol for "Time Displacement"

Tags: notation

Does the "Time Displacement" property of a wave function have an associated symbol?

> Amplitude = $\hat U$
>
> Period = $T$
>
> Ordinary frequency = $f$
>
> Angular frequency = $ω$
>
> Phase = $ϕ$
>
> Time Displacement = ?

The term appears in my college lecture notes:

[image]

Comment: Is this even a mathematical term?

Comment: $\mathrm d t$? $\Delta t$?

Comment: @tomasz I am asking because it appears in my college notes, so maybe - maybe not. It is calculated ϕ/ω so might just be my lecturer's weird way of saying phase shift

Comment: I would use $t_1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this analogy assume $\alpha > 0$.

The author of that text is simply using the term time displacement to mean the time it would take the lagging function to achieve the same $y$ value (displacement, field magnitude etc.) as the leading function.

In that sense $\Delta t$ is not a bad choice for a symbol. Especially considering that distance displacement is commonly represented by the symbol $\Delta x$.

Answer (score -1):

Physicists use $t$ for time, the variable, units second.